# Does surgical text 'sushrut samhita' mention circumcision ? Has this procedure ever been performed on a man in ancient india for medical reasons?

Tags: samhita

We know its associated mostly with abrahamic religions. But considering that we have our own surgical treatises like 'sushrut samhita' .

was this ever done in ancient india to cure medical problems ?

Comment: Circumcision was started among ancient Jews because in Kaliyuga people identify with body and normally think that purpose of life is gratification of senses. Circumcision of genitals shifts consciousness away from genitals by reducing sensitivity as mind of every being seeks pleasures. Its a forceful trick to make Jews spiritual, like Naga sadhus make sadhaks impotent on becoming naga, just like in Sanatana Dharma, Brahmcharya is told to be followed till age 25.

Comment: Jews didnot have any yogis, scriptures dealing with intrinsic animal behavior ,controlling mind through methods of yoga, like Hindus have via Yoga Sutras. Judaism started with just 12 tribes roaming within deserts of Israel who had to struggle for basic needs rather than naturally gifted Indian subcontinent and its vast recorded ancient spiritual history dealing with Gyana-Bhakti Yoga.Circumcision does impact spirituality and wisdom in someway not complete though as its external alone, Jews have most noble prize winners till now including some of extraordinary geniuses like Albert Einstein.

Comment: This question is off-topic.